# Opening file geodatabase using ESRI android API

Tags: java, android, gis, esri

for some time I am trying to open file godatabase on android using ESRI api in version 10.2.

I have a file godatabase made with Arccatalog 10.1. It contains one layer. I can open it in Arcmap so everything looks fine here.
The geodatabase is in folder named android.gdb
I copied it to microSD card and tried to open it using this code:

```
new com.esri.core.gdb.Geodatabase("/mnt/sdcard2/android.gdb");
```

The "/mnt/sdcard2/android.gdb" file exists and is a folder and I have read and write permissions.

I get a RuntimeException with the message that the goedatabase file could not be opened.

Anyone had similiar issues with that ?

Answer (score 1):

The ESRI runtime api for android wont be able to open that kind of database. It uses a proprietary version of a geodatabase built in SQLLite.  You will need to publish a service in ArcGisOnline or ArcServer 10.2 and call the GeodatabaseSyncTask object in order to get a version of your database in the right format onto the device. On your published feature service you will need to make sure Sync is enabled. Then you can utilize this code to call your feature service and store it locally.  This code is based on this ESRI sample -- https://developers.arcgis.com/android/sample-code/offline-editor/

```
public void LoadGdb(UserCredentials credentials, Polygon extent, SpatialReference spatRef){

    mapExtent = extent;
    mapSpatialRef = spatRef;
    String replicaUrl = callingActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.feature_service_url);
    gdbTask = new GeodatabaseSyncTask(replicaUrl, credentials);

    gdbTask.fetchFeatureServiceInfo(new CallbackListener<FeatureServiceInfo>() {

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCallback(FeatureServiceInfo objs) {
          if (objs.isSyncEnabled()) {
            requestGdbInOneMethod(gdbTask, mapExtent, mapSpatialRef);
          }
        }
      });
}

protected void requestGdbInOneMethod(GeodatabaseSyncTask geodatabaseSyncTask, Polygon extent, SpatialReference spatRef) {

     GenerateGeodatabaseParameters params = new GenerateGeodatabaseParameters({0, 1}, extent,
             spatRef, true, SyncModel.LAYER, spatRef);

    CallbackListener<String> gdbResponseCallback = new CallbackListener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onCallback(String obj) {

          try {
                   // This onCallback gets called after the generateGeodatabase
                   // function on the GeodatabaseSyncTask is called.
                   // You can store a reference to this database or you can load it
                   // with your code and point it to the gdbFileName location
                   Geodatabase myGeodatabase = (Geodatabase)obj;

          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        }
      };

      GeodatabaseStatusCallback statusCallback = new GeodatabaseStatusCallback() {

          @Override
          public void statusUpdated(GeodatabaseStatusInfo status) {
            showMessage(callingActivity, status.getStatus().toString());
          }
        };

            //  !!   THE gdbFileName is a string of the path and filename
            // where the geodatabse will be stored.
        geodatabaseSyncTask.generateGeodatabase(params, gdbFileName, false, statusCallback, gdbResponseCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To load a local file you need to use ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.1 or higher to generate a Runtime Geodatabase file with a *.geodatabase file extension. See the instructions here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00660000045q000000